# slow initialization of o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

We upgraded our project ,mainly springboot 1.4.3 , java 7 to java 8.

After that ,during application startup, it takes more than 8 minutes to move past 'Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler' '

We have activiti dependency also

Below is the log

```
2017-01-24 14:56:15 INFO  o.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl:82 - ProcessEngine default created
2017-01-24 14:56:15 INFO  o.a.e.i.a.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor:86 - Starting up the default async job executor [org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor].
2017-01-24 14:56:15 INFO  o.a.e.i.a.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor:121 - Creating thread pool queue of size 100
2017-01-24 14:56:15 INFO  o.a.e.i.a.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor:126 - Creating executor service with corePoolSize 2, maxPoolSize 10 and keepAliveTime 5000
2017-01-24 14:56:15 INFO  o.a.e.i.a.AcquireTimerJobsRunnable:45 - {} starting to acquire async jobs due
2017-01-24 14:56:16 INFO  o.a.e.i.a.AcquireAsyncJobsDueRunnable:44 - {} starting to acquire async jobs due
2017-01-24 14:57:22 INFO  o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler:165 - Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
2017-01-24 15:05:37 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:534 - Looking for @Controlle
```

Any relation to java8 and slow startup ?

Comment: that's ridiculously slow. Does that happen *all the time* or *sometimes*?

Comment: Some of our team member says its loading fast after 6 restart !

Comment: I have just two thoughts here: a bug or not enough memory and you are hitting a HUGE stop the world in GC

Comment: not enough memory could be possible - aws 1GB env - will try with big RAM, Thanks

Comment: aws? you are using amazon? you should have tagged that, it might help someone reading the question

Comment: I have not worked or deployed to aws, but did a bit of googling and reading some things, and it turns out this could be aws related. But I'm not sure at all. http://serverfault.com/questions/690656/why-sometimes-aws-ec2-works-really-slow might a be a start.

Comment: slow in dev VM also.Before upgrade used to start fast in dev vm. dev vm is in own server